# ActiveRecord ConnectionPool - exception handling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using ConnectionPool to check out/in db connections.

So if there's no exception, everything works as expected. A connection is checked in at the end.

But what if there's an exception in the block of code that's wrapped around with_connection?

Does the AR connection still get checked in automatically into the pool?

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
   m = SomeModel.find(something)
   m.foo = "bar"
   m.save!
   etc

   #EXCEPTION RAISED HERE
   # WHAT HAPPENS?

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be fine, from the [source code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html#method-i-with_connection) an `ensure` block is used which releases the connection at the end.

```
def with_connection
  ...
ensure
  release_connection(connection_id) if fresh_connection
end
```